# Why doesn't groovy use classpath argument?

Tags: groovy

Invoking a groovy script using CLASSPATH prefix as follows works fine:

```
CLASSPATH=/path/to/classes groovy -e "(new stuff.XMLUtils()).printIt('test string')"
```

but changing it to use the classpath arg doesn't:

```
groovy -classpath /path/to/classes -e "(new stuff.XMLUtils()).printIt('test string')"
```

and gives the error:

```
script_from_command_line: 1: unable to resolve class stuff.XMLUtils
```

Can anyone explain why this is? (The stuff.XMLUtils is just some groovy script i've compiled into /path/to/classes
)

I've done some investigation, and using the following groovy script to dump the classloader

```
def printClassPath(classLoader) {
  println "$classLoader"
  classLoader.getURLs().each {url->
     println "- ${url.toString()}"
  }
  if (classLoader.parent) {
     printClassPath(classLoader.parent)
  }
}
printClassPath this.class.classLoader
```

With the `-classpath` arg, i see no entry in the classloader for the passed in classpath arg, (in fact, the only directory is the current working dir), e.g.:

```
groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@4911b910
groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader@18203c31
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@35a16869
- file:/usr/share/java/ant.jar
- ... (removed for brevity)
- file:/home/admin/groovy/
sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@77cde100
- file:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_23/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
- ...
```

Using the `CLASSPATH=...` version shows that the PWD entry above is replaced by the value i've set in the variable.

And if I add debug to the groovy shell executable, the difference in the java call is that the `-classpath` arg version adds no entry to java's classpath entry (which is ultimately why it's giving a class not found error), but the `CLASSPATH=...` version does add the path.

Is this a bug in groovy?

EDIT: simple failing example

```
- - - - xu.groovy
package stuff
def printIt(string) { println string }
- - - -

groovyc -d classes xu.groovy
groovy -cp classes -e "(new stuff.xu()).printIt('test')"  # fails
CLASSPATH=classes groovy -e "(new stuff.xu()).printIt('test')"  # works
```

If I remove the package and references to `stuff` the failing example will work fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering this myself because I found a solution to the problem.

I was using the default groovy packages from yum in fedora, however found many issues (errors starting groovysh etc, unable to find jline package etc), and have wholly moved over to using downloaded versions from codehaus.org, and manually specifying GROOVY_HOME and editing path to invoke the downloaded one instead.

Now all my examples work as expected.

Answer (score 5):

I'm on MSYS/Win32 + groovy 2.2 RC1 and have another twist:

```
groovy -cp "./*" script.groovy    // Works!
```

but

```
groovy -cp some.jar script.groovy  // ... not
```

For some reason, although some.jar was in the same directory the above would not work out in my case.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. I just tried to repeat your explained issue but everything seems to work fine (I made tests with Groovy-Version 1.8.6, 1.7.7 and 1.7.0 on my Ubuntu Computer).

So which version do you use and what is your operating system?

In the Groovy Bug Tracker I have found the following bug: [Command line option for classpath (--cp/--classpath) is broken on Windows](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-2628). But this bug just affects old versions of Groovy (1.5.2, 1.5.3 and 1.5.4). So maybe an upgrade of Groovy will help to fix your problem...

PS: Normally I just would comment this, but unfortunately I haven't enough points for doing this :).

Comment: I'm using Linux, Fedora 15. The version of groovy `Groovy Version: 1.8.0 JVM: 1.6.0_22`.

Comment: @Mark There isn't yet a groovy version 1.8.0 available at the official web site, so I cannot help you. I also have made a test with groovy version 1.8.2, but everything works fine. So I recommend you to upgrade groovy. Greetings

Comment: Did you try adding a package to the script you were testing? I've been able to successfully run `-classpath` or `CLASSPATH=...` if I remove the package statement and have everything at default package level, but as soon as I add the `package stuff` line to the top and compile, groovy doesn't seem to find it with the `-classpath` arg. I've tried this on another machine running 1.8.4 and still same problem. I've updated my question with a detailed example.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your example (with `package stuff` statement) works fine on my machine...